# Pandas to Excel (Merged Header Column)

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I want to convert my df to an excel sheet, but also want to add a header column to categorize all the columns. [image: Here is a screenshot without the merged column header]

[image: and the second picture shows the 'Financials' and 'Obs' headings]

For reproduction:

```
import pandas as pd
 # Create a Pandas dataframe from some data.
df = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [10, 20, 30, 20, 15, 30, 45]})

# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_simple.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

# Convert the dataframe to an XlsxWriter Excel object.
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')

# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.save()
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can create `MultiIndex`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':list('abcdef'),
         'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
         'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
         'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
         'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
         'F':list('aaabbb')
})
```

Specified new name of level with start and end column name:

```
L = [('OBS','A','C'), ('FIN', 'D','F')]
```

And then in list comprehension create `tuples` for [`MultiIndex.from_tuples`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples.html):

```
cols = [(new, c) for new, start, end in L for c in df.loc[:, start:end].columns]

print (cols)
[('OBS', 'A'), ('OBS', 'B'), ('OBS', 'C'), ('FIN', 'D'), ('FIN', 'E'), ('FIN', 'F')]

df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(cols)
print (df)
  OBS       FIN      
    A  B  C   D  E  F
0   a  4  7   1  5  a
1   b  5  8   3  3  a
2   c  4  9   5  6  a
3   d  5  4   7  9  b
4   e  5  2   1  2  b
5   f  4  3   0  4  b
```

Comment: what if I want only the 'OBS' and 'FIN' not the others?

Comment: @LeonRai - Not sure if understand, can you explain more?

Comment: above example provides 2 merged labels (OBS and FIN) and the others in the row below. What if I need only the OBS and FIN only? I tried with cols = [('OBS', ''), ('OBS', ''), ('OBS', ''), ('FIN', ''), ('FIN', ''), ('FIN', '')] but it creates an extra empty row below itself.

Comment: @LeonRai - duplicated columns are not recomended, because problem with select. If use `df['OBS']` it return all columns with `OBS`. But it is possiblem just assign `df.columns = ['OBS','OBS','OBS','FIN','FIN','FIN']`. Need same values in list like values in columns.

Comment: I tried that too, it creates multiple rows each letter in a row, weird.

Comment: @LeonRai - Not sure if understand.

Comment: F in the 1st row, I in 2nd, N in 3rd and so on

Comment: @LeonRai - hmmm, not sure. There is possible remove second level with empty strings by `df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(1)`

Comment: I tried that too, interestingly when removing the below rows, it resets the merge. Well, thank you, as a workaround the excess row can be eliminated by using python-excel (openxlsx, .. ) libraries. Seems like it's not possible with pandas.

Comment: Suppose I require 'OBS' to be a `field variable`, where it can take different `strings` values depending on the `dataframe's` content?

Comment: @Gathide - Waht means `field variable` ? Can you post new question - input data, expected ouput and your code?

Comment: Have asked the question, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69324898/pandas-dataframe-with-dynamic-title