# How to assign column names a superordinated name (common header) in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Assume a simple dataframe like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [1], 'B' : [0], 'value1' : [33], 'value2' : [23]})

df
   A  B  value1  value2
0  1  0      33      23
```

How can I assign superordinated column names s.t. I get a dataframe like:

```
             values
   A  B      value1  value2
0  1  0          33      23
```

This should be somehow possible using multiindexing, but I can't figure out how.

Pay attention to that `A` and `B` have no joined heading. Therefore

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['values'], df.columns])
```

is not enough. Hence it is not a duplicate.

I also tried:

```
 df[['value1','value2']].columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['values'], df[['value1','value2']].columns])
```

But unfortunately it does not assign the new column name to the original dataframe.

Comment: So for `A, B` is no header?

Comment: You just want to add an extra level?

Comment: ...so, something like `df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['values'], df.columns])`?

Comment: @jezrael Did you see my editing? I think it is not a duplicate, please reopen it.

Comment: @newandlost - yes, I see. But what you need is not possible, is necessary specify each level, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53700965/2901002) solution. Another idea is use `df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [1], 'B' : [0], 'value1' : [33], 'value2' : [23]})` and `df = df.set_index(['A','B'])` and then `df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['values'], df.columns])`, but not sure if need it.